# Exactness of the Tensor Functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products

This might turn out to be a very stupid question, so I apologize in advance, but it is confusing me a little bit.

I know in general that if $$M'\rightarrow M\rightarrow M''\rightarrow 0$$ is an exact sequence of $A-$modules, then $$M'\otimes_AN\rightarrow M\otimes_AN \rightarrow M''\otimes_AN \rightarrow 0$$ is an exact sequence for any $A-$module $N$.

If instead we are given an exact sequence of the form: 
$$M'''\rightarrow M'\rightarrow M\rightarrow M''\rightarrow 0$$ where $M'''$ is not the zero module (because I know that tensoring with a module doesn't necessarily take injective maps to injective maps), then I guess my question is why isn't the following an exact sequence as well?
$$M'''\otimes_A N\rightarrow M'\otimes_AN\rightarrow M\otimes_AN \rightarrow M''\otimes_AN \rightarrow 0$$

What is going morally wrong here? I guess i'm wondering where exactly is the proof of the first case failing to show that the second sequence is exact at $M'\otimes_AN$?

I would appreciate very much if anyone could clarify my confusion. I am probably just being stupid about this :/

Comment: FYI: We don't like exclamation points in titles (unless maybe you're asking about the game called "Bang!"). Also, note that $\to$ can be written `\to` and $\gets$ can be written `\gets`.

Comment: I'd like to say that I'd appreciate about a chapter's worth of coverage on this point in every algebra text.  Exact sequences and short exact sequences generally tend to be introduced as though they're the most obvious thing in the world, without any explanation as to why short exact sequences are special.

Comment: What proof of the first are you referring to? The proof of which I am aware uses thee fact that the tensor functor is left-adjoint to the $Hom$ functor, and that every functor which is left adjoint to some functor is right-exact.

Comment: Your last sequence has a typo: the $M$ as the right "factor" should be $N$ if you're asking what I think you're asking.

Answer (score 7):

Ok so we have an exact sequence

$$
M''' \to M' \to M \to M'' \to 0
$$

Let's break it up a bit. I'm going to denote by $\alpha$ the map $M' \to M$ and by $\beta$ the map $M \to M''$. Then we can break up the exact sequence above as two exact sequences

$$
M''' \to M' \to \operatorname{im} \alpha \to 0
$$

and

$$
0 \to \ker \beta \to M \to M'' \to 0.
$$

Tensoring, we see that the first becomes the exact sequence

$$
M''' \otimes N \to M'\otimes N \to \operatorname{im} \alpha \otimes N \to 0 \enspace \enspace \enspace (*)
$$

and the second becomes the exact sequence

$$
\ker \beta \otimes N \to M \otimes N \to M'' \otimes N \to 0 \enspace \enspace \enspace (**).
$$

From exactness of the original sequence we know that $\operatorname{im} \alpha = \ker \beta$ so that $\operatorname{im} \alpha \otimes N = \ker \beta \otimes N$. However, it is no longer necessarily true that this is a submodule of $M\otimes N$ as the tensor product with $N$ is not necessarily left exact.

By exactness of $(*)$, $\operatorname{im}(M''' \otimes N \to M' \otimes N) = \ker(M'\otimes N \to \operatorname{im}\alpha \otimes N = \ker \beta \otimes N)$. However, now the map $\ker \beta \otimes N \to M \otimes N$ might not be an inclusion, there might be a nontrivial kernel. Thus, $\ker(M'\otimes N \to \operatorname{im}\alpha \otimes N = \ker \beta \otimes N)$ might not necessarily be equal to the kernel of the composition to $M \otimes N$, $\ker(M' \otimes N \to M \otimes N)$. Therefore, the longer sequence might not be exact even though the two short exact sequences are.

This is the general idea even if we try to extend it. A long exact sequence is really just a bunch of short exact sequences at each step and tensoring won't always preserve the inclusion of that kernel and so it won't always preserve the long exact sequences.

A more concise way to say this is that tensoring does not preserve kernels, $\ker \beta \otimes N \neq \ker (\beta \otimes \operatorname{id}_N)$ in general so in general it can't preserve longer exact sequences where we need something mapping to a kernel to still stay exact.

Comment: Can you add a specific counterexample?

Answer (score 4):

### Some Counterexamples

There are many counterexamples to this statement - clearly, there has to be, for otherwise flat modules would be everywhere. And perhaps the best way to see why it fails is to examine some examples. Here is a class of examples that have two advantages: they are easy to compute with, and show something a little different than working over principal ideal domains (it's safe to ignore the parenthetical remarks):

Consider $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-the integer polynomial ring. Here is an example of an exact sequence of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-modules:

$$
0\to \mathbb{Z}[x]\xrightarrow{\alpha} \mathbb{Z}[x]^2\xrightarrow{\beta}\mathbb{Z}[x]\xrightarrow{\gamma} \mathbb{Z}/2\to 0
$$

The maps are defined by

- $\alpha(f) = (2f,xf)$
- $\beta(f,g) = 2g - xf$
- $\gamma$ the quotient map via the ideal $(2,x)$.

(This is just a special example of something called the Koszul complex given by the regular sequence $(2,x)$ - any two relatively prime elements generating a proper ideal will work, since $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a GCD domain.) Here are two examples to show why tensoring does not keep this exact:

### Example 1

One can apply the functor $\mathbb{Z}/2\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[x]}-$ to get the complex
$$
0\to \mathbb{Z}/2\xrightarrow{\alpha} \mathbb{Z}/2\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\xrightarrow{\beta}\mathbb{Z}/2\to\mathbb{Z}/2\to 0
$$
Here, $\mathbb{Z}/2$ is a $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ module via the quotient map $\mathbb{Z}[x]\to \mathbb{Z}/2$, so $2$ and $x$ act trivially, and hence $\ker\beta = \mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2$ whereas $\operatorname{Im}\alpha = 0$. In other words, $\operatorname{Tor}_1^{\mathbb{Z}[x]}(\mathbb{Z}/2,\mathbb{Z}/2) = \mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2$. **Note**, to compute derived functors we "should have" chopped off the $\mathbb{Z}/2$ but that doens't matter since we are not computing the zeroth homology.

### Example 2

Here is a more interesting example, still working with $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-modules: Consider the following $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-module: the underyling abelian group structure is given by $V = \mathbb{Z}/4\times\mathbb{Z}/4$. There is an endomorphism of $V$ as abelian groups given by the matrix

$$T=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Letting $x$ act via $T$ makes $V$ into a $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-module. Applying $V\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[x]}-$ to the exact sequence gives a chain complex
$$
V\xrightarrow{\alpha} V^2\xrightarrow{\beta} V\to V\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[x]}\mathbb{Z}/2\to 0
$$

Now $\beta([(1,0),(1,0)]) = (2,0) - (2,0) = 0$. However, $\alpha(a,b) = [ (2a,2b), (2a + 2b,b)]$. So the complex is not exact at $V^2$.

### To Produce Your Own...

...find rings that have non-flat modules and modules with free resolutions of length at least two. Most of the time you should get a winner.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, you already knew that, when 
$$
M'''\to M'\to M\to M''\to 0
$$
is exact,
$$
M'''\otimes_AN\to M'\otimes_AN\to M\otimes_AN\to M''\otimes_AN\to 0
$$
could fail to be exact when $M'''=0$, and you tried to avoid that difficulty by assuming that $M'''\neq0$.  Unfortunately, that doesn't really avoid the problem. If you have a counterexample with $M'''=0$, then you can manufacture a counterexample another with any non-zero $M'''$ that you want. Just put your desired $M'''$ in place of the $0$ and define the map $M'''\to M'$ to be the zero map.

OK, so probably the next thing to try is to assume that not only the module $M'''$ but also the map $M'''\to M$ has to be non-zero.  That avoids the construction I just described, but it still doesn't avoid the problem.  Take your counterexample for the case where $M'''=0$, and modify it as follows.  Put any desired non-zero $M'''$ in place of the $0$, and also replace $M'$ with $M'\oplus M'''$.  Then define the map from $M'''$ to (the new) $M'$ to be the inclusion of the second summand.  EDIT: I should have also said that the map from the new $M'$ to $M$ is the composition of the projection from the new $M'$ to the old with the original map from the old $M'$ to $M$.

In effect, what I've done here is to splice together your original short exact sequence with the (even shorter) exact sequence $M'''\to M'''\to 0$.  That's the simplest case of (the reverse of) what Dori Bejleri explained about breaking longer exact sequences into several short exact sequences.